# Add "show all" option to AJAX filter (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've followed [this guide](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-post-filters.html) on how to create a AJAX filter for posts that sorts the posts by categories and displays them dynamically in a div. I've modified the code to also display a subcategories container for each of the categories.

I would now like to add an option that let's the user reset the filter by pressing "All" in the filter options. In the guide I've used for this, a user asks for this function but I'm having trouble understanding how exactly to achieve it. The instructions are:

> 1. Add the option in HTML,
> 2. If option is checked do not add any parameters to the $args array of WP_Query().

I don't really know how to do this. I've put the PHP that handles the form in my `functions.php`. This is the code in functions.php so far:

```
    function misha_filter_function(){
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date', // we will sort posts by date
        'order' => $_POST['date'] // ASC или DESC
    );

    // for taxonomies / categories
    if( isset( $_POST['categoryfilter'] ) )
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'hide_empty' => 0,
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter'],
            )
        );
        if( isset( $_POST['subcategoryfilter'] ) )
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'hide_empty' => 0,
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['subcategoryfilter'],
            )
        );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
            echo '<div class="gallery-item">';
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail-size' ); $url = $thumb['0'];
                the_post_thumbnail('large', array('data-src'=>$url, 'data-sub-html'=>$query->post->post_title));
            }
            echo '<p>' . $query->post->post_title . '</p></div>';
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo 'No posts found';
    endif;

    die();
}
```

This is the HTML/PHP:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
                                <?php  echo "<div id='maincategories'>"; ?>
<?php
            if( $terms = get_terms( 'category', 'parent=0&exclude=1' ) ) : // to make it simple I use default categories

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
            echo '<label><input type="radio" name="categoryfilter" data-filter-slug="' . $term->slug . '" value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</label>'; // ID of the category as the value of an option
                    endforeach;
                    echo "</div>";
            endif;
    ?>
            <!-- ### HIDDEN CONTAINERS FOR THE SUBCATEGORIES ### -->    
            <!-- Väggar/tak -->
    <?php
            if( $terms = get_terms( 'category', 'child_of=32' ) ) : // to make it simple I use default categories
                    echo "<div class='subcategories' data-filter-id='32'>";
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
            echo '<label><input type="radio" data-category-id="' . $term->parent . '" name="subcategoryfilter" value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</label>'; // ID of the category as the value of an option
                    endforeach;
                    echo "</div>";
    endif;
    ?>

            <!-- Golv -->
            <?php
            if( $terms = get_terms( 'category', 'child_of=41' ) ) : // to make it simple I use default categories
                    echo "<div class='subcategories' data-filter-id='41'>";
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
            echo '<label><input type="radio" data-category-id="' . $term->parent . '" name="subcategoryfilter" value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</label>'; // ID of the category as the value of an option
                    endforeach;
                    echo "</div>";
    endif;
    ?>

            <!-- Objekt -->
            <?php
            if( $terms = get_terms( 'category', 'child_of=26' ) ) : // to make it simple I use default categories
                    echo "<div class='subcategories' data-filter-id='26'>";
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
            echo '<label><input type="radio" data-category-id="' . $term->parent . '" name="subcategoryfilter" value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</label>'; // ID of the category as the value of an option
                    endforeach;
                    echo "</div>";
    endif;
    ?>

            <!-- Projekt -->
            <?php
            if( $terms = get_terms( 'category', 'child_of=31' ) ) : // to make it simple I use default categories
                    echo "<div class='subcategories' data-filter-id='31'>";
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
            echo '<label><input type="radio" data-category-id="' . $term->parent . '" name="subcategoryfilter" value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</label>'; // ID of the category as the value of an option
                    endforeach;
                    echo "</div>";
    endif;
    ?>
```

I'm thinking that the way to do this is to put this in the PHP/HTML...

```
echo "<label><input type='radio' name='all' > All</label>";
```

...and then put this is the functions.php:

```
if( isset( $_POST['all'] ) )
        $args = array();
```

But that doesn't seem to solve it. I'm a beginner at PHP and Wordpress so help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here's the jQuery as well:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
            $("#filter #maincategories label").on("click", function () {
              if($(this).children("input").attr("checked")){
                return;
              } else {
                $(".subcategories input").removeAttr('checked');
                $(".subcategories label").removeClass("active");
                }
            })
            $('#filter').submit(function () {
                    var filter = $('#filter');
                    var filterID;
                    $.ajax({
                            url: filter.attr('action'),
                            data: filter.serialize(), // form data
                            type: filter.attr('method'), // POST
                            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                                $("#response").removeClass("active");
                                filter.find('button').text('Processing...'); // changing the button label
                                console.log(filter.serialize());
                                $(".subcategories").hide();
                                $(".subcategories").removeClass("active");
                                filterID = filter.serialize().match(/categoryfilter=(\w+)&/)[1];
                                $(".subcategories[data-filter-id=" + filterID + "]").addClass("active").show();

                            },
                            success: function (data) {();
                                $('#response').html(data); // insert data
                                if ($("#response").data("lightGallery"))
                            $("#response").data("lightGallery").destroy(true);
                            createLightGallery();
                            setImageFormat();
                        }
                    });
                return false;
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok look,

first of all put in your HTML something like this:

```
echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='all' > All</label>";
```

Second step - make some changes at the beginning of your filter PHP function:

```
if( empty( $_POST['all'] ) ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['categoryfilter'] ) )
            $args['tax_query'] = array(
                array(
                    'hide_empty' => 0,
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter'],
                )
            );
      if( isset( $_POST['subcategoryfilter'] ) )
            $args['tax_query'] = array(
                array(
                    'hide_empty' => 0,
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $_POST['subcategoryfilter'],
                )
            ); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! The strange thing is that I get the posts, but they don't update into the `#response` div. Instead the browser sends me to a new unformatted page listing the posts. Any ideas why this is happening? I've added the jQuery code to the original post if that has something to do with it.

Comment: Nevermind my last question. It seems to work now. Although I'm experiencing another issue where when I click the "All" option and then on another option, the `all=on` is still in the beginning of the `filter.serialize()`. Do you think this has to do with the way I show and hide the subcategories and the way that filtering is added or is it because of something else? I've made the "All" option a radio like the other options, so it should not behave like a checkbox where the user has to click it again to deactivate.

Comment: The "All" option is a radio option like the rest at the moment, but when I click the "All" option, every option I click from there gets the `all=on` in the `filter.serialize()`. Here's a [GIF](https://imgur.com/a/v5ZoK) of the behaviour.

Comment: your radios must have the same name attribute and the different values. The codу above should be changed as well

Comment: if( !empty( $_POST['all']  ) && $_POST['all'] !== 'on' ) {

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159418/discussion-between-tobiasg-and-misha-rudrastyh).

Comment: Okay, so – I misunderstood. :)
I gave the "All" option `name="maincategories"` and then changed your snippet to `if( !empty( $_POST['maincategories'] ) && $_POST['maincategories'] !== 'on' ) {`. I got confused by the naming. Works like I wanted it to know. Thanks you so much!

Comment: great :) I'm glad you've figured it out